# Get the name form the URL in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have got a url by using

```
var url = window.location.href;
console.log(url);
```

This is the url

```
http://www.myproject.com/wp/?edit_project=797#step2=project
```

Now i want get the step2 from this url. Any clue how to get this only from the url.

Comment: split on `#` then split on `=`

Comment: are you saying you the fragment after the `#`, or that you want to then parse that fragment?

Comment: split `window.location.hash` by `=`, then get the second item in the resulting array

Answer (score 0):

window.location.hash returns "#step2=project". And you need to parse it out(there is no restriction for the hash part of url).

Answer (score -3):

This will work:

```
var startIndex = url.indexOf("step2");

var step2 = url.substr(startIndex);
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.